# How to get file path,name,creation date, last modification date,and the file extension inside this directory in a CSV file or excel file?

Tags: java, python, c, shell, powershell

I 'am New here and actually it's the first time i ask in a forum because i'am really blocked,i hope i will find an answer here.

i have a very big directory, and what i was asked to do is to know how many files do we have on it especially office files  (.doc .docx.ppt .pptx .xls .xlsx) i'am talking about more then 50000 documents .i tried a lot of small scripts in powershell i didn't success. i would like to mention that it's my first time which scripting so please would you make the answer easy to follow .

i need the file path,name,creation date, last modification date,and the file extension inside this directory  in a CSV file or excel file

if anyone has any other suggestions with any other programming languages it cold help too.

Comment: If you have tried powershell scripts, show us what you have tried and what part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

This Powershell command should work:

-Recurse Gets the items in the specified location and in all child items of the location (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)

```
$Path = "c:\somepath"    
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | select Directory,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Extension | Export-Csv c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly what i need ..i would like to know what kind of other information i can get about files